# How to get last offset Number directly or to filter the offsets in NodeJS Kafka Consumer

Tags: node.js

I am using a simple consumer/producer in Kafka NodeJS. My producer is sending messages which I am easily getting in consumer. Producer and Consumer code is below. In Consumer, I ws expecting that offset.fetch() gives me all offset IDs of today, but it doesnot. KIndly guide me that how I can get results from this method and also mention a method that directly gives the last offset number in the topic of any partition. I also want to know that how can I filter offsets in the coming streaming. e.g: If I want to get only last 20 messages in my consumer?

My producer is:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var Producer = kafka.Producer;
var Client = kafka.Client;
var client = new Client('localhost:2181');
var producer = new Producer(client);
producer.on('ready', function () {
    producer.send([
        { topic: 'test', key:'key1', partition: 0, messages: ['banana','carrot','lemon','apple','melon','kiwi','mango','avacado'], attributes: 0}
        ], function (err, result) {
        console.log(err || result);
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

My Consumer is:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var Consumer = kafka.Consumer;
var client = new kafka.Client('localhost:2181');
var offset = new kafka.Offset(client);
offset.fetch([
    { topic: 'test'  }
], function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);

});
var consumer = new Consumer(
        client,
        [
            { topic: 'test', partition: 0}
        ],

        {  autoCommit: false, autoCommitIntervalMs: 5000,  fetchMaxWaitMs: 100, fromOffset: true, fetchMinBytes: 1, fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 10
        }
    );
consumer.on('message', function (message) {
       console.log(message);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I was also in a situation where I need to get massage from the current time.I did it by fetching offset value of latest message, for which I passed *current time* and *number of offset values* to **offset.fetch([ ])** . Then by getting the offset value I just passed it to Consumer API and retrieved message from that time.

```
 offset.fetch([
    { topic: topicname, partition: partition, time: Date.now(), maxNum: 1 }
 ], function (err, data) {
    // data 
    // { 'topicname': { 'partition': [999] } } 
       var consumer = new Consumer(
            client,
                  [
                   { topic:topicname,
                     partition:partition,
                     offset:data[topicname][partition][0]}
                    ],
                    {
                        autoCommit: false,
                        fromOffset: true,
                    }
           );
           consumer.on('message', function (message) {
                  console.log(message);
           });
      });
```

this will give you messages from the current time. you can calculate time 20 min before and can get offset value of the message occurred 20 min before.

Comment: What's `maxNum` for?

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up to @anand's answer.  In the offset payloads, you can change the time field to -1 or -2, instead of a date for the following results.

```
// When time is -2, your response will be {topic: {partition: [lowestOffset]}
{ topic: topicname, partition: partition, time: -1, maxNum: 1 }

// When time is -1, your response will be {topic: {partition: [highestOffset, lowestOffset]}
{ topic: topicname, partition: partition, time: -2, maxNum: 1 }
```

The '-1' was especially helpful for me as I can just set my offset equal to the highest known offset for testing.

Comment: What's `maxNum` for?